# How to remove 800 kHz signal noise in long wires?

Tags: noise, wire, oscillation, ribbon-cable, ringing

I have a simple setup with Raspberry PI and [level shifter chip](https://www.renesas.com/us/en/document/dst/74alvc164245-datasheet) (3 V to 5 V), connected to some [neopixel LEDs](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/product-files/1138/SK6812+LED+datasheet+.pdf) via ribbon cable (~30 cm in length) and then with thin solid copper wires (varying from ~10 cm to ~50 cm). Example of how this looks in real life:

[image]

[image]

When running the system without connecting to the LEDs, on an oscilloscope I see the perfectly square signal but when everything is connected I get following image:

[image]

How is it possible to get rid of these spikes?

Comment: The datasheet of the LED controller is full of (not only spelling) mistakes, so I would be very, very cautious when taking information stated there as granted.

Comment: What in the world is going on in img2? Once you connect up the LEDs you're closing a loop which appears to be giving you massive amount of induction which is causing the ringing.

Comment: @horta, yes I understand that but what I should do to reduce it?

Comment: Doing some back of the napkin math, if you've added in an LC oscillator circuit, your L*C combo = 2e-15. Effectively, you'll want to reduce your L and C. The reason I point out your img2 being unwieldy is because it looks like there's a ton of added capacitance and possibly some inductance to it. Why're you making wires setup like that across a whole bunch of copper pads?

Comment: Are they driving LEDs, or is it a digital control signal? Slowing the rising edges should help reduce the ringing which can be acheived using a series resistor at the output of the level shifter (could add them in line with the ribbon cable connector).

Comment: @TomCarpenter. Yes they are driving LEDs, currently level shifter outputs are directly connected to LEDs inputs.

Comment: Probably another good question is whether you actually need to get rid of the spikes. If you're driving the LEDs directly, I have a suspicion they can handle that. I'm guessing this is an image of the output of the level shifter, have you checked the LED side to see if you see the same oscillating waveform?

Comment: @horta, indeed they are working but quite unstable

Comment: Try what @TomCarpenter says, it will be series termination, and you still need to terminate, don't know how much but use "R + C (series)", shunt that to the end of the line. How to provide the return path will be the challenge with your construction. If you are up to production, you need to approach from the system level.

Comment: Please post the schematics. There are so many things that can cause this, such as simply probing the lines wrong with the scope so the ringing may not even exist. If it is real, it could be due to missing bypass caps and not using source termination for impedance matching. Please note that the level shifter chip is of ALVC type which has incredibly fast and strong outputs which can cause ringing when driving light loads. Maybe the component is just far too fast what the system needs and can handle.

Comment: UPDATE, thanks to everyone for help, attempted @TomCarpenter suggestion which improved signal quality by a lot, now it is very close to perfect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ringing you see on the pulse edges is due to the various parasitic elements in your circuit. Your long wires will have a certain inductance, and then the parallel wires will have capacitance between them. Together these parasitics form a resonant LC circuit, in your case resonating around 800kHz.

By placing a resistor in series with the signal lines, you can to a certain extent damp the oscillations as the resistor dissipates the energy stored in the resonant circuit - essentially you form a damped RLC circuit. You can tune this resistor value to match your circuit - the larger it is, the more damping you get, but also the more rounded the waveform edges will become.

In your case I'd start with something on the order of 100Ω, placed in series with each of your signal lines, somewhere close to the level shifter outputs. You could place them inline with the ribbon cable connector, or cut the traces on the PCB and solder on small SMD resistors.

I can't tell from your image whether or not you have bypass capacitors on your level shifter supply rails - these should be ~100nF capacitors placed as close as possible to the VCC and GND pins of the level shifter. The bypass capacitors will help supply the initial current surge caused by the outputs switching state, which would help to overcome any parasitic inductance in the power supply lines.

---

With the fast edges of a square-ish waveform, you can also start to see over/undershoot caused by transmission line effects (signal reflections), but that is unlikely to be the main issue here, and the damping resistor should help with that too by slowing down the waveform edges and so removing some high frequency components.